# Adding a class to <li> element with helper method ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my issue is: This helper will be used in the view and also add classes to the 'li' element, except class 'red', which should be added if the following condition is true. Does anybody see something I have to change to make this work?

```
def navigation_item_with_message(body, url, options = {})
count = options.delete(:count) || 0
body = "#{body} (#{count})"
li_classes = ['ribbon', 'ribbon-inprogress']
li_classes << options[:li_class] = 'red' if count > 0 navigation_item(body, url, options)
li_classes.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: What on earth is this line supposed to do `li_classes << options[:li_class] = 'red' if count > 0 navigation_item(body, url, options)`?

Comment: What is the return value supposed to be?

Comment: The old code was this:
   `def navigation_item_with_message_count(body, url, options = {})
    count = options.delete(:count) || 0
    body = "#{body} (#{count})"
    options[:li_class] = 'red' if count > 0
    navigation_item(body, url, options)
  end`

Comment: @Iceman, this line should add 'red' class to the array above, but only if the condition is true.

Comment: Yes, but the last statement of the line, `navigation_item...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to solve it.

```
def navigation_item_with_message(body, url, options = {})
 count = options.delete(:count) || 0
 body = "#{body} (#{count})"
 li_classes = [options[:li_class]]
 li_classes << 'red' if count > 0
 options.merge!(:li_class => li_classes.join(' '))
 navigation_item(body, url, options)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure what the snippet you provided does, since I can't see the implementation of `navigation_item`. However here's a way to do what you want:

```
li_classes = ['ribbon', 'ribbon-inprogress']
li_classes << 'red' if count > 0
li_classes.join(' ')
# You can also do
# li_classes = "ribbon ribbon-inprogress #{count > 0 ? 'red' : ''}"
content_tag(:li, class: li_classes) do
  # function that returns an HTML or plain string
end
```